# D3 Line chart - Render Queue

Tags: performance, d3.js, queue

Can we render a D3 line chart using Render Queue?http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/3341641/

I have a JSON with around 50,000 elements in it. My browser crashes when I try to draw a graph with this much amount of data.

Code is:

```js
function lineChart(data, id){
 // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
 var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 // Parse the date / time
 var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
 // Define the div for the tooltip
 var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
  .attr("class", "tooltip")    
  .style("opacity", 0);
 // Set the ranges
 var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
 var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

 // Define the axes
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

 // Define the line
 var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.loadaverage); })
   
 // Adds the svg canvas
 var svg = d3.select(id)
  .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.loadaverage; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.selectAll('path')
   .data(pos)
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", valueline(data))
   .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()  
     .duration(200)  
     .style("opacity", .9);  
    div.html(d.time + "<br/>"  + d.loadaverage)
     .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")  
     .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
    })     
   .on("mouseout", function(d) {  
    div.transition()  
     .duration(500)  
     .style("opacity", 0); 
   });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
}
```

Comment: Note: I am using D3 version 3

Answer (score 0):

Render Queue uses canvas, which, with 50k elements, you probably should use too. Unfortunately, d3 v3 doesnt support canvas. If you can upgrade to v4, then you will gain canvas support and much greater performance. Conceptually, you certainly can do progressive rendering with lines, but I do not know if Render Queue directly supports it. We ultimately rolled our own progressive renderer for our product.

Be forewarned, if you do switch over to canvas, you'll have to rethink how you are doing your mouseevents because on canvas, you dont have elements onto which you can attach listeners.